# Replacing a ComboBox's Drop-Down with a Menu

Tags: wpf, combobox, menu

How would I replace a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx)'s default drop-down list with a menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realized that it was a lot easier to style a `<Menu>` to look like a `<ComboBox>` than it was to make a `<ComboBox>` show a menu.

Here's a [blog post](http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2011/01/21/675/combobox-displaying-a-drop-down-menu) describing how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are after is for the ComboBox dropdown to *look* like a menu then you don't need to replace anything as the ComboBox accepts arbitrary content.

E.g.

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Margin="25" MaxHeight="25">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <Separator />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
        <Separator />
        <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this thought, Benjamin. Unfortunately, I need the functionality of menu items. However, simply placing <MenuItem>s in the combobox doesn't work because doing so causes them to loose some of their behavior. Wrapping them in a <Menu>, makes a menu bar appear in the box instead of an expanded menu, so that option appears to be out, too. Using a <ContextMenu> as the item in the combobox causes an exception. :-(

Comment: What functionality of menus are you trying to replicate?